# I wish to permanently plot initial Day Range

Tags: pine-script, trading

I wish to plot two lines with the distance of the Average day range from the open. I am using the following code for plotting the Average Day range it works well, but I want to plot the line permanently after the first candle is printed. Actually this code updates for each candle and new low and new high.

```
//@version=4        
//
study(title="DR", shorttitle="DR-1D", overlay=true)

is_forex_pips       = input(title="Display average range as forex pips?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
daily_adr           = input(title="ADR display limit", type=input.integer, defval=300, minval=0)
weekly_adr          = input(title="AWR display limit", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=0)
monthly_adr         = input(title="AMR display limit", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=0)
yearly_adr          = input(title="AYR display limit", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=0)
daily_adr_length    = input(title="ADR Length parameter", type=input.integer, defval=5, minval=0)
weekly_adr_length   = input(title="AWR Length parameter", type=input.integer, defval=5, minval=0)
monthly_adr_length  = input(title="AMR Length parameter", type=input.integer, defval=1, minval=0)
yearly_adr_length   = input(title="AYR Length parameter", type=input.integer, defval=1, minval=0)

new_bar(res) =>
    change(time(res)) != 0
adr(length) =>
    range  = high - low
    //range = high - close
    sma(range[1],length)
    // sma(range[1], length)
adr_high(adr) =>
    high - low < adr ? low + adr : close >= open ? low + adr : high
adr_low(adr) =>
    high - low < adr ? high - adr : close >= open ? low : high - adr
to_pips(val) =>
    is_forex_pips ? val/syminfo.mintick/10 : val/syminfo.mintick
draw_adr_hilo(hi_level, lo_level, res, adr, level_color) =>
    var line hi_line = na
    var line lo_line = na
    var line hi_line_per = na
    var line low_line_per = na
    if new_bar(res)
        line.set_x2(hi_line, bar_index)
        line.set_x2(lo_line, bar_index)
        line.set_extend(hi_line, extend.none)
        line.set_extend(lo_line, extend.none)
        hi_line := line.new(bar_index, hi_level, bar_index, hi_level, extend=extend.right, color=level_color)
        lo_line := line.new(bar_index, lo_level, bar_index, lo_level, extend=extend.right, color=level_color)

        //hi_line_per:= line.new()
        //label.new(bar_index, hi_level, "AveR: " + tostring(to_pips(adr)), style=label.style_none)
        label.new(bar_index, hi_level, "D: " + tostring((adr)), style=label.style_none)
    if not na(hi_line) and line.get_x2(hi_line) != bar_index
        line.set_x2(hi_line, bar_index)
        line.set_x2(lo_line, bar_index)

//--------------ploting the first line permanantely -------------//


// locHigh = 0.0
// locLow = 0.0

// h = security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", adr(daily_adr_length), lookahead=true)
// l = security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", low, lookahead=true)

// if hour == 9 and minute == 15
//     locHigh := hi_line
//     locLow := low_line
// else
//     locHigh := locHigh[1]
//     locLow := locLow[1]

// plot(locHigh)
// plot(locLow)

//
// Daily
//
day_adr      = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', adr(daily_adr_length), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
day_adr_high = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', adr_high(day_adr), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
day_adr_low  = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', adr_low(day_adr), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24


if ((timeframe.isintraday or timeframe.isdaily) and daily_adr > 0 and timenow - time < one_day * daily_adr)
    draw_adr_hilo(day_adr_high, day_adr_low, 'D', day_adr, color.olive)


//
// Weekly
//
week_adr      = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', adr(weekly_adr_length), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
week_adr_high = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', adr_high(week_adr), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
week_adr_low  = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', adr_low(week_adr), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
one_week = one_day * 7
if ((timeframe.isintraday or timeframe.isdaily or timeframe.isweekly) and weekly_adr > 0 and timenow - time < one_week * weekly_adr)
    draw_adr_hilo(week_adr_high, week_adr_low, 'W', week_adr, color.orange)


//
// Monthly
//
month_adr      = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'M', adr(monthly_adr_length), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
month_adr_high = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'M', adr_high(month_adr), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
month_adr_low  = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'M', adr_low(month_adr), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
one_month = one_day * 30
if ((timeframe.isintraday or timeframe.isdwm) and monthly_adr > 0 and timenow - time < one_month * monthly_adr)
    draw_adr_hilo(month_adr_high, month_adr_low, 'M', month_adr, color.fuchsia)


//
// Yearly
//
year_adr      = security(syminfo.tickerid, '12M', adr(yearly_adr_length), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
year_adr_high = security(syminfo.tickerid, '12M', adr_high(year_adr), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
year_adr_low  = security(syminfo.tickerid, '12M', adr_low(year_adr), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
one_year = one_day * 365
if (yearly_adr > 0 and timenow - time < one_year * yearly_adr)
    draw_adr_hilo(year_adr_high, year_adr_low, '12M', year_adr, color.red)
```

And also I want to plot fibo levels in between that levels. I am very new to pine script.

Comment: Your code is cheating by user future data because of your use of `lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on` in your `security()` calls. We recommend you study [How to avoid repainting when using security() - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/) and repost clean code.

Comment: This script is too complicated to understand.....

Comment: I felt Bar color is so easy to implement. How do you think barcolor cheats user. I felt Repainting is seriously helped me a lot while trading.

Comment: The problem I mentioned has nothing to do with repainting. The "repainting" in the referenced article is simply because that's its main subject. Your problem is that with lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on and no `[1]` offset on your data in `security()`, you are using future data on historical bars, which is impossible in real life. So your script is showing you performance on historical bars that can never be replicated in the realtime bar.

Comment: Ohh I got you..... Thank you will read that article in this aspect.....